# Objective-C - Change the address of a passed-in object pointer

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

Let's say that I've got a method like:

```
- (void)reassignPassedObject:(void *)block;
```

and it's called as in

```
NSLog(@"self 1: %@", self);
[myController reassignPassedObject:^(){return self;}];
NSLog(@"self 2: %@", self);
```

I want to reassign the 'self' reference to another object, like this:

```
- (void)reassignPassedObject:(void *)block {
    id holder = block();

    if ( YES ) {
        id newObject = nil; //or NSString or NSArray
        //do something such that output second log is "self 2: (newObject...)"
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

It seems like it should be fair game since we're just talking about reassigning pointers.  I will worry about release/retain in a specific implementation.  The challenge here that confuses me is:

- It involves id instead of straight pointers
- It involves a block-passed variable
- It involves having to somehow reassign the address of the object inside block() where all we have access to is the local holder object.

Ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do all this???

Comment: Aside from that fact that we have no idea what you're trying to do or why you'd want to do it, is there any reason you don't just use a double pointer as a method argument, then change your object pointer that way?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't change `self` inside your code, unless in the beginning of `init...` via `self=[super init...]`.

And I have no idea why you want to use blocks, or what motivates you to do all this, but if you insist on changing what a pointer points to, the most standard C-based way is to pass the pointer to the variable. e.g.

```
-(void)changeObjectPointedBy:(id*)p{
        *p=@"foo";
}
```

Then this can be used as

```
NSString*q=@"bar";
[self changeObjectPointedBy:&q];
NSLog(@"%@",q); // prints "foo"
```

Note the extra `&` and `*` in the code. Before trying to abuse blocks, I'd recommend you to learn straightforward C.

If you insist on using a block, I would do:

```
-(void)passMyObjToBlock:(void(^)(id))block
{
     block(@"foo");
}
```

which can be used as

```
__block NSString*p=@"bar";
[self passMyObjToBlock:^(id obj){
       p=obj;
}];
NSLog(@"%@",p); //prints "foo"
```

Or, another way is to

```
-(void)reassignPassedObject:(id*(^)())block{
     id*holder=block();
     *holder=@"foo";
}
```

and then

```
id* pointerToSelf=&self;
[foo reassignPassedObject:^(){return pointerToSelf}];
// self is now @"bar"
```

Note the distinction between a "pointer to the object" and a "pointer to the pointer to the object". In order to change what is pointed to by `self`, you need to pass the pointer to `self` to the function. This is a fundamental limitation of C, and there is no way you can do this without using one pair of `&` and `*`.

Comment: Your pointer technique works great, and I may mark this as the answer if we can't get the blocks technique working.  Your blocks example attempted to use the block to reassign the value, not the result of the block as my example did, so it was no help.  My example is vastly simplified over the real code that's being executed, which actually involves nested blocks defined at different code points.  I also want to add that this is all occurring inside of init... where I think it's fair game to set self to nil or a custom subclass of self as in a class cluster.

Comment: If so, could you edit your question to provide more context so that we can answer you in a more effective way? I'm afraid you simplified your original question too much.

Comment: The question does provide all cogent information.  How do I reassign the original 'self' as it is represented by 'holder'?  All the linkages are there.

Answer (score 1):

While you can assign self (it is common practice to do so in the `init` method) what you're doing seems very, very wrong.

A [great post on Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html) describes how all this works in Objective-C and could probably shed some light on this.

Are you trying to accomplish something specific?  Or are you just hoping to understand the language better?

Comment: I am performing this in init; I want to do some dynamic reassigning based on passing self to another object with compile-time-unknown selectors and blocks.  In fact I'm creating the class during runtime as a sort of class cluster using block imps.  My question seems legit, although I admit very, very exotic.  The issue is I only have access to 'self' and 'id', both of which aren't standard pointer arguments but special obj-c keywords that are harder to work out logically.

Comment: `self` and `id` are both almost standard. `self` is just a hidden argument supplied to any method: internally, `self` is the first, `_cmd` is the second argument. So `self` inside a method behaves just as if it's an argument to a function. `id` is just a pointer to an opaque type.